# Checking the Proxy Status via Power Shell

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, proxy

I am planning to write a Script which will check the status of my proxy. I want to try loading the websites in IE and my script want to observe the time taken to load the website via Proxy.

Please let me know if we have any possibilities to take the time consumed by websites to load.

Comment: see this script[link](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2008/04/22/cheesy-web-server-performance-test-with-powershell.aspx) example for run `script.ps1 http://yoursite.com/ 15"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Invoke-WebRequest](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=217035) command for that. It has properties to configure your proxy server settings.

To time you can use Get-Date() before & after and subtract time values.
Use get-member to find out all methods you can use on the returned date object.

```
get-date | get-member
```